# Android Holoeverywhere DatePreference error

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-holo-everywhere

I am using the Holoeverywhere library. I should have a preference where the user picks a date. I put this preference in my file like this

```
<org.holoeverywhere.preference.DatePreference
        android:key="preference_birth_date"
        android:summary="@string/preference_birth_date"
        android:title="@string/preference_birth_date" />
```

When i start the preference screen I get the following error:

```
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.gauss.istrabike/dev.gauss.istrabike.settings.UserProfilePreferencesActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:228)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference._SharedPreferencesImpl_XML.getLong(_SharedPreferencesImpl_XML.java:263)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference._SharedPreferencesImpl_XML.getLong(_SharedPreferencesImpl_XML.java:263)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.Preference.getPersistedLong(Preference.java:412)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.DatePreference.onSetInitialValue(DatePreference.java:144)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:178)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:607)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:74)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:40)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:1)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.app.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:262)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.app.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.app.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:194)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.app.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:164)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.app.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:158)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:384)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:284)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at dev.gauss.istrabike.settings.UserProfilePreferencesActivity.onCreate(UserProfilePreferencesActivity.java:68)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
01-17 23:11:10.719: E/AndroidRuntime(26307):    ... 11 more
```

When I remove the preference from the XML file everything works fine. I only set the preference in the XML I didn't do anything in code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string value with key `preference_birth_date` in your store. It caused by using  `EditTextPreference` earlier with the same key. Just clear app data or change key to something else.

Comment: Oh, OK...that worked. Thank you very much... you save my life :)

Comment: btw...when I set a onDateSetListener, in the method onDateSet() when I  get the month value, the value is always 1 less than it should be.

When I set January the month value is 0, and when I set December the month value is 11... Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your not yet  implemented class 'ComponentInfo' has problem with casting string to long, look into code of that class or override 'onCreate' method in any subclass of 'ComponentInfo'.

Comment: I think ComponentInfo doesn't have anything to do with this :)